# Ruby: rescue doesn't rescue from thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rescue

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

begin
    #code in this block doesn't matter at all, it just needs to produce errors.
    [1, 2].each do |i|
        a = Thread.new do
            errory
        end
    end 
    a.join 
rescue Exception
    puts 'error!'
end
```

raises `/home/lakesare/Desktop/multithreading/test.rb:6:in 'block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method 'errory' for main:Object (NameError)` instead of returning `error!` for some reason.
If `Thread.new {}` isn't wrapped in `each {}`, block is rescued properly.
Why is that? How to rescue my thread properly in this case?

**edit:** I found wrapping `begin-rescue-end` block in identical block helps. But one question lingers - why isn't one rescue enough?

**edit:** wrapping in another rescue block helps, but not always - sometimes it still doesn't rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with what you have written that I think are clouding the issue for you.

1. You shouldn’t set `Thread.abort_on_exception = true` unless you really want your program to abort when an exception occurs in a secondary thread. Typically, you’d only want this set to true for debugging. If set to false, any exception raised in a thread will cause that thread to exit but will only be visible to the parent thread when you `join` with the child thread.
2. In your code above, when you attempt to join with a thread, the variable `a` is out of scope. Thus you should get a `NameError` there too.
3. Even if this were in scope, you are only joining with one of your threads.

You should find the following more predictable:

```
Thread.abort_on_exception = false

begin
  threads = [1, 2].collect do |i|
    Thread.new do
      errory
    end
  end
  threads.each { |thread| thread.join } # You might want to use a ThreadsWait here instead.
rescue Exception
  puts 'error!'
end
```